# Formal language representation of program

Tags: formal-languages, formal-methods

I have numerous records, composed of words. Each word gets translated into vectors, with a variable number of channels, provided that that word exists in a specific lookup dictionary.

For n number of words in every record, based upon c number of channels that each vector-based representation of the words possesses, a function f is fed this stream of data and outputs a probability p.

n and c are both constants.

How might this be represented in formal language?

Comment: Why are you dissatisfied with your current explanation?  Why does it need to be formal?  What do you consider to be formal?  Also, we usually prefer questions that will be useful to others in the future, even if they're not facing the exact situation you are in (as it is unlikely anyone else in the future will ever need to translate exactly that specific statement into formal language); is there any conceptual understanding that you're not clear on, that might help both you and someone else in the future?

Comment: What's the point of the channels? What is a channel? What is *this stream of data*, in what way is it a stream?

Comment: @reinierpost Channels are synonymous with neurons (artificial neural networks). The data is a stream insofar that it is ordered data.